# Amazon Linux EC2 Instance Keeps Crashing

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

It doesn't matter what flavor of Linux I use. It is really frustrating. I need to get to the bottom of this.

Here is link to the wp-config.php file: http://pastebin.com/JtZjDx8E
Here is a link to the error_log: http://pastebin.com/vgAMvFca

If my problem gets solved, I owe you a beer!

Comment: Did you look at the system logs from was console

Comment: Seems like SSL issue and not able to connect to mysql. Are you using SSL?

Comment: Are you using an RDS or mysql server on the same EC2?  If you are using mysql server on the EC2 instance can you also provide us the mysql configuration found at `my.cnf`. I noticed also this error **Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.**. You need to provide us with further details how you setup the server.